# When can I '@' tag a user?

Tags: support, comments

I have noticed that there are times when I am unable to '@' tag a user or trigger the auto-complete popup. Sometimes, even when I type `@username` in a comment, SE automatically removes the tag when posting. Is this a bug, or are there specific conditions for tagging users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's explained in horrific detail in [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) but the gist of what you need to know here are thus:

- If there are only two users leaving comments, it is not necessary and the system will know to notify the other party. Therefore it will strip it as a courtesy of clean comments.
- Use the @ notation when there are more than two users leaving comments on the same post.
- If you need to @ ping another user leaving comments on the same post, don't do it at the front of your comment. Work it in naturally somewhere in the middle or end.
- The owner of the post is always notified and it's pointless and noisy to @ ping them in the comments.

Comment: That last point is obsolete: @-addressing the owner (i.e. you in this case) will be stripped from the comment. This is fairly new and probably to reduce noise. This comment started with "(at)random" when written.

Comment: On a post with multiple users, you may see some @ ping the OP at the head of the comment, out of some convention even if they don't need to

Comment: Ah yes, if there are other possible recipients, it's kept in.